# Number of Spaces that Intersect a Space of Dimension l

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a vector space of dimension $N$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$, and let $V\subseteq W$ be a $l$-dimensional subspace of $W$.

My goal is now to show that the number of $l$-dimensional subspaces $U$ that intersect $V$, such that $\dim (U\cap V)=r$ for some $r<l$ is independent of the chosen $V$.

So far I have done the following:

---

Let $V$ and $\tilde{V}$ let be $l$-dimensional subspaces of $W$. So there exists bases such that
\begin{align*}
V=\text{span} (v_1,\dots,v_l) && \text{and} && \tilde{V}=\text{span}(\tilde{v}_1,\dots,\tilde{v}_l).
\end{align*}
These bases can be expanded to bases for $W$, so
\begin{align*}
(v_1,\dots,v_l,w_{l+1},\dots,w_N) && \text{and} && (\tilde{v}_1,\dots,\tilde{v}_l,\tilde{w}_{l+1},\dots,\tilde{w}_N)
\end{align*}
both will be a basis for $W$. Now there exists an isomorphism $\phi$ mapping the first basis to the second basis, that is $\phi(v_i)=\tilde{v}_i$ for $i=1,\dots ,l$ and $\phi(w_i)=\tilde{w}_i$ for $i=l+1,\dots N$.

Suppose $U$ is another $l$-dimensional subspace of $W$ such that $\dim(U\cap V)=r$ for some $1\leq r\leq l$. So $U$ (after renaming) has a basis of the form
$$U=\text{span}(v_1,\dots v_r,u_{r+1},\dots ,u_l)$$

Now define $\tilde{U}$ as
$$\tilde{U}=\text{span}(\tilde{v}_1,\dots,\tilde{v}_r, \tilde{u}_{r+1},\dots, \tilde{u}_l),$$
where $\tilde{u}_i=\phi(u_i)$ for $i=r+1,\dots,l$. Thus $\tilde{U}$ is a $l$-dimensional subspace of $W$ because $\phi$ is an ismorphism.

Clearly $\dim(\tilde{U}\cap \tilde{V})\geq r$. 
Now suppose, for contradiction, that $\dim(\tilde{U}\cap \tilde{V})> r$. Then there exists a $j$ such that $r<j\leq l$ and $\tilde{v}_j\in \tilde{U}$. This means for appropriate $c_i\in \mathbb{F}_{q}$ for $i=1,\dots, l$
$$
\tilde{v}_j=c_1\tilde{v}_1+\dots+c_r\tilde{v}_r+c_{r+1}\tilde{u}_{r+1}+\dots +c_l\tilde{u}_l.
$$
Thus by applying $\phi^{-1}$ to this equation we have 
$$
{v}_j=c_1{v}_1+\dots+c_r{v}_r+c_{r+1}{u}_{r+1}+\dots +c_l{u}_l,
$$
meaning that $v_j\in U$ for $r<j\leq l$. This contradicts that $\dim(U\cap V)=r$.
Now we have proved that if an $l$-dimensional subspace $U$ intersects $V$ in dimension $r$, then the $l$-dimensional subspace $\tilde{U}$ will intersect $\tilde{V}$ in dimension $r$. Similarly it can be proved if $\tilde{U}$ intersects $\tilde{V}$ in a $r$-dimensional subspace, then $U$ will intersect $V$ in a $r$-dimensional subspace.

And thus a space $U$ intersects $V$ in dimension $r$ if and only if $\tilde{U}$ does the same for $\tilde{V}$.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good to me. The first few lines of your argument prove (if we replace $l$ by arbitrary $0 \leq k \leq n$) that

> the group $GL(W)$ acts transitively on the space $Gr(k, W)$ of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $W$,

(the space $Gr(k, W)$ is the *Grassmannian (manifold)* of $k$-planes in $W$), and in particular this says that for any $g \in GL(W)$ the map $\Phi_g : Gr(k, W) \to Gr(k, W)$ defined by $U \mapsto g(U)$ is a bijection. This can be used to simplify the remainder of your argument.

For any $U \in Gr(l, W)$, any $g \in GL(W)$ maps $U \cap V$ to $g(U \cap V) = g(U) \cap g(V)$, and so this intersection must have dimension $r := \dim (U \cap V)$. So, $\Phi_g$ restricts to a bijection of the set $$\{U \in Gr(l, W) : \dim(U \cap V) = r\}$$
to itself.